# Entity Framework many to many with 2 tables

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, many-to-many, fluent-interface

### Scenario

I'm working with an existing database that contains two tables, which create a many-to-many relationship because they are not properly normalized. The table structures look like the following.

```
Employee (table)

 - PersonId
 - JobId
 - JobTitle
 - OfficeLocation
 - EmailAddress

Projects (table)

 - PersonId
 - JobId
 - Supervisor
 - ProjectName
```

I have the following POCOs:

```
public class Employee{
    public int PersonId{get;set;}
    public int JobId{get;set;}
    //...
    public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects{get;set;}
}

public class Project{
    public int PersonId{get;set;}
    public int JobId{get;set;}
    //...
    public virtual Employee Employee{get;set;}
}
```

I'm wiring this up using an EF Fluent API call

```
this.HasRequired(p=>p.Employee)
.WithMany(e=>e.Projects)
.HasForeignKey(p=>new {p.PersonId, p.JobId});
```

### Problem

The situation is that some employees have multiple job titles and locations which generates multiple Employee records, and then each employee has multiple projects. The problem is that `Project.Employee` is returning multiple records and generates the following error:

> A relationship multiplicity constraint violation occurred: An
>   EntityReference can have no more than one related object, but the
>   query returned more than one related object. This is a non-recoverable
>   error.

I've attempted to change the Project class to

```
public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employee{get;set;}
```

with

```
this.HasMany(e=>e.Courses)
.WithMany()
```

But EF expects there to be a 'tweener table relating employee to projects.

I realize there are problems with the database structure, but at this time I'm left to work with this setup. Is it possible to do this type of relationship using Entity Framework or does any have a recommendation on how to tackle this?

Comment: AFAIK does this not work without the additional table, neither in EF nor in SQL in general.

Comment: Quick question, are you using PersonId, JobID as the primary key on your employee entity?

Comment: Yes, it is treated as a segmented key.

Comment: Is that the entire key? You said multiple job titles and locations, implying that the duplication is coming from the multiple locations. It doesn't sound like you're describing a many-to-many relationship here, just a rather ugly one-to-many.

Comment: You're right. Ideally, it is a one-to-many. There should be one Employee with multiple Projects. The additional job titles and locations is forcing me (because of Entity Framework) to treat it as a Many-to-Many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first recommendation would be to fix the schema, but if that is not possible, I ran into a somewhat similar issue on our project and what worked best for us was creating two DBContexts. In your case, each context would have a one to many relationship going in each direction. Depending on which way you wanted to query the data, either Employee->Project or Project -> Employee would dictate which DBContext you used. If you are using the fluent API you can keep all of your pocos the same and just have two different mapping config files. Here is a blog post I wrote on the issue.

http://blog.mvmiller.net/2013/10/working-with-legacy-database-schemas.html

Comment: I've actually tried doing something similar as a work-around. I created a method GetEmployee off of the Project class. When called, queries the Employee DbSet from the DbContext and gets the FirstOrDefault() Employee and returns it. Not elegant, but gets the job done.

The problem is performance. The extra DB Call for a collection of 20+ projects becomes noticeable very quickly.

Comment: My hope was to eliminate the additional DB call by getting EF to "respect" the relationship and just do an Include().

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest you make another associative Entity One to Many for Each of Them 
call the associative Entity (EmployeeProjects) which is One to Many for both of Employee and Projects PK will be ProjectID+EmployeeID.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say Entity - you are suggesting I add a new table to the database to create the One-to-Many relationship?

Comment: I had considered the idea. I realized that when new records are added on one Employee or Projects tables, I would need to generate a new record to the EmployeeProjects table. To do this I would need an off task process or trigger, which I felt was overkill.

Answer (score 0):

looking at your poco class it appears that many to many relation is not well defined
Try changing project to
    
    `public class Project{
        public int PersonId{get;set;}
        public int JobId{get;set;}
        //...
        public virtual ICollection <Employee> Employees{get;set;}
    }`

```
changing 
public virtual ICollection&lt;Employee&gt; Employees{get;set;}
</code>
```

and do check there must be table with name ProjectEmployee or visa versa in DB.